# Run a program using LWJGL on Linux terminal

Tags: java, linux, lwjgl

So I'm using a software using LGJWL(v3), and the program won't run on Linux.
All I want to do is to run the server on Linux terminal, with no GUI environment.
The program has plugins supported and there's no guarantee that plugins won't use LWJGL.
Is there any way to create something like "null" window that does not rely on any GUI native.

Comment: The program uses OpenGL. Thanks for information. I will try Xvfb. There was information that OSMesa can be used.I think I'll try both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The program worked fine after installing xvfb & osmesa.
I also note that LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT had to be 0 for the program to work.